# minimized workbook has no restore button

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

When I minimize work books they do not have a restore (or maximize) button, just the close button. Makes it hard to restore them! Any ideas? is there a registry setting that is messed up that makes the minimized size too small? This is for all workbooks I use including brand new ones (not converted from 2003) The workbooks are otherwise normal.

Comment: Has this always been an issue or is this a new problem? When did it start? Until you have enough reputation, you can post a link to a screenshot on a free image site and we will add it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The workbook should be able to alternately be restored by selecting the Excel icon in the task bar, which expands to offer you all your currently opened workbooks.

Answer (score -1):

If you've just got one worksheet open, you cant 'restore it' from the taskbar. I dont know a fix yet but a work around to restore the minimized worksheet, use key combo: Ctrl-F5